# Redirecting to Login page instead of refreshing the token in Nuxt auth

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

I implemeted the Nuxt auth module in my project. Now I have 2 tokens, Access token (30 minutes maxAge) and Refresh Token (8 Hours maxAge).

What I want to achieve is refresh the Access token every 30 mins using the Refresh token. After 8 hours, The person should be logged out since the Refresh token got expired.

But currently the person is being redirected to the login page after the Access token is expired. Sometimes it'll update the Access token (Only if the user is engaging in the app, If the user is idle it is redirecting to login page.)

I'm using "@nuxtjs/auth-next": "5.0.0-1648802546.c9880dc" package

Below is the nuxt.config.js

```
auth: {
    redirect: {
        login: "/",
        logout: "/",
        callback: "/dashboard",
        home: "/dashboard",
    },
    strategies: {
        local: {
            scheme: "refresh",
            token: {
                property: "tokens.access.token",
                global: true,
                type: "Bearer",
                maxAge: 60 * 30, // 30 minutes
            },
            refreshToken: {
                property: "tokens.refresh.token",
                data: "refreshToken",
                maxAge: 60 * 60 * 8 // 8 Hours
            },
            user: {
                property: "user",
                autoFetch: false,
            },
            endpoints: {
                login: { url: "/users/login", method: "post" },
                refresh: { url: "/users/refresh-tokens", method: "post" },
                user: false,
                logout: "",
            },
            autoLogout: true,
            tokenRequired: true,
            tokenType: 'JWT',
        },
    },
    plugins: [{ src: "~/plugins/axios.js", ssr: true }],
}
```

Below is my /plugins/axios.js file

```
export default function ({ store, app: { $axios }, route, redirect }) {
  // the two interceptors here will run in every $axios requests
  // On Request for this purpose is used to add the Bearer token on every request
  $axios.onRequest((config) => {
   let accessToken = store.state.token;
   if (accessToken && config.url !== "/users/login") {
     config.headers.Authorization = "Bearer " + accessToken;
   }
   return config;
  });

  // On Error, when there is no Bearer token or token expired it will trigger logout
  $axios.onError(async (error) => {
   // Error status code
   const statusCode = error.response ? error.response.status : -1;
   if (route.path !== "/" && statusCode === 401) {
     return redirect("/");
   }
  // return Promise.reject(error);
  });
}
```

Comment: You could have a middleware that is checking if your token is expired, and then `router.push` the user to the desired endpoint.

Comment: @ki In my middleware I'm checking context.$auth.loggedIn, but like you said I could check whether token expired or not. Does nuxt-auth provide something to check whether token is expired or not. If possible I can use this.$auth.refreshTokens() to manually update tokens. NB: maxAge should have work, right?

Comment: Hm, not sure if it have something baked in. But having a cookie is usually fast/simple enough that I didn't really needed to look beyond in terms of check.

Comment: If you don't mind can you elaborate what I need to do if I want use a cookie to check-whether the token is expired. I can try it out asap.

Comment: Get the cookie, compare the current time to the expiration time of the cookie mainly. Then, you can `router.push` to any interesting place you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the `autoLogout: false` fixed my issue. Now it's calling refrsh token API properly.